# ignore invalid or null date field in dwl 1.0 mule 3

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I'm trying to validate the date and datetime in input payload. I've to validate the request and remove the field if the date or datetime format is not correct or null. In case of correct format or null value it's working as expected but in case of wrong format it's throwing error **"Cannot coerce a :string to a :localdatetime"**

How can i fix this in dwl 1.0 (mule3)

```
    Input:
    {
      "date1": "2021-02-12 00:00:00",
      "date2": "2021-02-12",
      "date3": "2021-02-121",
      "date4": "2021-024-123 00:00:00",
      "date5": "",
      "date6": null
    }

    Expected Output:
    {
      "date1": "2021-02-12 00:00:00",
      "date2": "2021-02-12",
    }

    code: 
    %dw 1.0

    %output application/java
    %function transformDate(dt) (dt as :date {format: "dd/MM/yyyy"} as :string {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"})
    %function changeDateTime(cdt) (cdt as :localdatetime {format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"} as :string {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"})
    %function isEmpty(value) (value!=null and value!="")


    ---
    {
        (date1: changeDateTime(payload.date1) as :date) when (isEmpty(payload.date1)),
        (date2: transformDate(payload.date2) as :localdatetime) when isEmpty(payload.date2),
        (date3: transformDate(payload.date3) as :localdatetime) when isEmpty(payload.date3),
        (date4: changeDateTime(payload.date4) as :localdatetime) when isEmpty(payload.date4),
        (date5: transformDate(payload.date5) as :localdatetime) when isEmpty(payload.date5),    
        (date6: transformDate(payload.date6) as :localdatetime) when isEmpty(payload.date6)         
    }
```

Comment: which case is failing in your example? Please provide the attribute name from the input and the full output.

Comment: @aled I've added the full input and expected output. date3 and date4 format is not correct that is why it's failing

Comment: The full error message shows what is the error, which input is not matching with which expression. That would be helpful.

Comment: @aled error message I have already mentioned. "Cannot coerce a :string to a :localdatetime"

Comment: But not the 'full' error message. I added it in my answer because it adds to the context.

Comment: @aled basically when i am getting other format then it's considering it as string that is the issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when trying to parse the input dates with patterns that are not a match DataWeave throws an error:

```
Message               : Exception while executing: 
%function changeDateTime(cdt) (cdt as :localdatetime {format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"} as :string {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"})
                               ^
Cannot coerce a :string to a :localdatetime, caused by :Text '2021-02-12 00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 2.
```

In DataWeave 2/Mule 4 you have the [try()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-runtime-functions-try) function to test if some expression fails. Unfortunately there is no equivalent in DataWeave 1/Mule 3. As alternatives you can use one of these methods:

- Isolate each expression that could fail into a separate script and encasulate it into an error handler that can catch the expression.
- Use the method described in this [KB article](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Parsing-variable-format-date-strings-using-DataWeave) to guard each pattern conversion with a condition and try to test if the pattern will match before attempting it. Example:

```js
(dateStr) -> dateStr as :localdatetime {format: "E, d LLL u H:m:s O"} when (dateStr contains /^[A-z][A-z][A-z],/) 
             otherwise (dateStr as :localdatetime {format: "E LLL d H:m:s u"} when (dateStr contains /^[A-z][A-z][A-z]\s/) 
             otherwise dateStr as :localdatetime {format: "cccc, d-LLL-u H:m:s O"})
```